# How to get a string sent in body of a request inside a Spring restful webservice?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I have a spring web service method where i want to get a string as a parameter. The string is sent in body of the request. My web service class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{uid}/openchart")
public class OpenChartWebService {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveABC(@PathVariable("uid") Long uid, 
            @RequestBody String myString) {
            System.out.println("sent string is: "+myString);
            return "something";
    }
}
```

My request in body is :

```
   {
      "name":"Ramesh"
    }
```

But this is not working. This shows "Bad Request" HTTP error(400). How to send a string in a body and how to get a string sent in a body inside webservice method?

Comment: try specifying media type on @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: It didnt work. If i do @RequestBody(SomeUserDefinedClass object), then i can get that particular object. I want only one string parameter to send therefore I dont want to develop an overhead of creating another class.

Comment: The bad request error is gone. Now, I get "sent string is: null" when i run this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Leon suggests, you should add the media type to your request mapping, but also make sure you have Jackson on your classpath.  You'll also want to change your @RequestBody argument type to something that has a "name" property, rather than just a String so that you don't have to convert it after.

```
public class Person {
    private name;

    public getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

If your data object looked like the above, then you could set your @RequestBody argument to Person type.

If all you want is a String, then perhaps just pass the value of "name" in your request body rather than an object with a name property.